# Exception in Pyspark Structured Streaming while reading from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

**Environment**: Spark 2.4.0

I have included spark-sql-kafka-0-10 jar, and it's of the same version as that of the Spark I am using.

Here's the exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<clinit>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:882)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:865)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have [kafka-clients](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients) jar in my classpath. Adding it fixes the missing class exception

Starting the spark-shell with the packages option will work too:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0
```

Comment: That should be included as part of spark-streaming-kafka packages

Comment: It would be if I start the spark-shell with the packages option and passed `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0`, which would download the dependencies. I just downloaded the spark-sql-kafka jar and added to classpath. Edited my answer